# PyPy 5.8.0 (Windows) and lxml: how to install

Tags: python, xml, windows, lxml, pypy

I just install PyPy on my system and it's awesome, super fast.

My problem is that I can't install "Lxml" via pip.

What is the correct way to install **LXML on PyPy for Windows**?

WHL? Manual Installation?

Thanks in advance